# What primary weapon sticks out the least?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So sometimes in CS:GO I like to camp in a corner and wait to catch unsuspecting enemy players by surprise. But sometimes they are able to know where I am because my gun's barrel sticks out.

So my question is what primary weapon sticks out the least? So I know AWP seems to be the longest, but is there a shorter weapon than that? For example, If I'd like to stick with rifles, what's the shortest?

Comment: couldn't you just look at the model and see?

Comment: @rapitor there's no 3rd person, and even with the model it's hard me to judge just from eyes only. For example, I can't really tell if there's a difference in length with the AUG vs the M4, but at the same time the AUG looks around the same size as Galil, and that itself seems to be close to the FAMAS.

Comment: Pretty sure it is the FAMAS if only looking at rifles. No evidence to back that up though. Using the M4A4 or removing the silencer from the M4A1 would make them fairly short also. You could also try facing the wall (and thus your gun isn't a problem) and use sound to determine when an enemy is approaching.

Comment: For rifles, I would guess that the FAMAS would be the shortest for CT, and the Galil would be the shortest for T.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The info here is taken from this youtube video: [CS GO : Which corners can you hide in?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgPBu8ZwOL4) by [3kliksphilip](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmu9PVIZBk-ZCi-Sk2F2utA):

> Weapons from shortest to longest (not limited to rifles):
>
> 1. Grenades
> 2. MP9
> 3. P90 - sticks out to side.
> 4. Mac-10
> 5. Aug
> 6. MP7
> 7. Knife
> 8. Famas
> 9. P2000
> 10. P250
> 11. Glock
> 12. Tec-9
> 13. Fiveseven
> 14. Zeus
> 15. USP
> 16. UMP-45
> 17. M4A4
> 18. Deagle
> 19. Sawed Off
> 20. Bizon
> 21. Mag-7
> 22. Dualies
> 23. M4A1
> 24. XM1014
> 25. Galil
> 26. M249
> 27. Nova
> 28. USP-S
> 29. AK47
> 30. SG553
> 31. Scar-20
> 32. Negev
> 33. M4A1-S
> 34. G3SG1
> 35. SSG08
> 36. AWP (Longest by a mile)

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen here on any Arqade question.

Comment: @FrankV all credit to 3kliksphilip, he did the leg work, I simply shared the content.

Comment: did I miss it or is the cz not listed?

Comment: @ColinD good spot, I just checked and it's not listed. Will see if I can dig anything up on it.

Answer (score -1):

The M4A1 S is the longest weapon in the game due to the way the characters hold Auto rifles